# Group by wordpress posts by meta value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have about 2000 woocommerce products on my wordpress database, each product has an ACF select field named **place** which value is **local** or **regional**.

My goal is to group by each products by the place meta field so i I thought that following code do the job :

```
class Search
{
  public function __construct() 
  {
      add_action("pre_get_posts", [$this, "filterProducts"]);
      add_filter('posts_groupby', [$this, 'groupByFilter'] );
  }
  public function filterProducts($query){
    // ... code
    // This where i alter que query 
   // .. code
   return $query;
  }
  public function groupByFilter($groupby)
  {
     global $wpdb;
     return $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key = 'place'";
  }
}
```

But, this not working, **and output only one product** while the expected result is :

-- **LOCAL**

- product
- product

-- **REGIONAL**

- product
- product

I know **foreach** over each product is a solution, but for performance reasons i am looking do to it directly throught main query.

NOTE : if it helps, I use timber and in the search.php file I have this piece of code :

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context["posts"] = new \Timber\PostQuery();
// print the results
dump($context['posts']);
```

**UPDATE :**
The sql results output this query :

```
SELECT 6288gjvs_posts.* FROM 6288gjvs_posts 
WHERE 1=1  
AND 6288gjvs_posts.post_type = 'product'  
AND (6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'complete' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'paid' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'confirmed' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'unpaid' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'pending-confirmation' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'cancelled' 
OR 6288gjvs_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY 6288gjvs_postmeta.meta_key = 'place' 
ORDER BY 6288gjvs_posts.menu_order, RAND(1348526234)
```

Copied it and pasted on phpmyadmin with error output :
#1054 - Champ '6288gjvs_postmeta.meta_key' not known in group statement

So i left join the post meta :

```
SELECT 6288gjvs_posts.post_title, 6288gjvs_posts.ID, 6288gjvs_postmeta.post_id  
FROM 6288gjvs_posts  
LEFT JOIN 6288gjvs_postmeta 
ON 6288gjvs_posts.ID = 6288gjvs_postmeta.post_id 
AND 6288gjvs_posts.post_type = 'product'  
GROUP BY 6288gjvs_postmeta.meta_key = 'place'
```

Without success

## UPDATE 2

Hello, so finally i opted with two queries, i didn't found any solution, now I have to manage two paginations in one page :(. If someone find a solution, i always follow up this post and may be useful for others.

Thank you for your helps

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: Hello, yes but i don't understand what is the relation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter your posts by a meta key, you should definitally take a look at [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/).

So like you did with 'tax_query' in the 'pre_get_posts' filter, you should add another query in the main query like this:

```
$meta_query[] = array(
                'key'     => 'place',
                'value'   => 'your_value',
                'compare' => '=',
        );
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
```

I hope you find this usefull and it solves your problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you, the tax_query i added is not important, just to say that i alter the query inside the block, but from your code, what i should add to "your_value" ? the "local" or "regional" value?

Comment: Replace "your_value" with regional to get the posts with place=regional and replace with local for the posts with meta place=local

Comment: Thank you, but the excepted results is posts list grouped by "local" and "regional", it just not a simple filter by meta_value, i want as output grouped results.

Comment: I am not sure if wordpress queries have an option for the GROUP BY statement. If not and you want the output to be grouped by, you either have to create a custom SQL query and run it with $wpdb->get_results($your_custom_sql) or try to group the posts manually with php instead of directly grouping the query results.
The second solution is not the most efficient, because you have to get the post meta for each post and then check the value.

Comment: i updated the post, left join with post meta without success, have you any advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier and advisable to get posts using [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) instead of modifying the SQL codes that may affect other post types and queries. In your scenario where you are getting WooCommerce products, use [WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query). Below is an example that will get you products with `meta_key = place`

```
function get_xx_products()
{
    $args = array(
        'my_custom_var'         => array(
            array(
                'key'           =>  'place',
                'value'         =>  '',
                'meta_compare'  =>  'EXISTS'
            )
        ),
        'status'                => 'publish'
    );
    return wc_get_products($args);
}

function hook_my_custom_var($query, $query_vars)
{
    if (!empty($query_vars['my_custom_var'])) {
        $query['meta_query'] = $query_vars['my_custom_var'];
    }
    
    return $query;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'hook_my_custom_var', 10, 2);
```

You can read more about it here - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Comment: Hi, very rich informations, thank you, i'll check that